# Split a string of words by uppercase words

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a set of names where the surname is in capital and first and middle names are normal, e.g.

```
OBAMA Barack
DEL MONTE Alfredo
```

I want to split these in

```
"OBAMA", "Barack"
"DEL MONTE", "Alfredo"
```

What is the pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Obama is Barack Obama's surname.

Comment: Thanks. Although it was an example, I change it to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [
...    ' '.join(items)
...    for _, items in itertools.groupby('DEL MONTE Alfredo'.split(), str.isupper)
... ]
['DEL MONTE', 'Alfredo']
```

Comment: I consider it elegant, but I honestly doubt if it's what most Pythonistas would consider Pythonic. I seem to think a little differently about some things :) My first thought was of `itertools.takewhile`, but I settled on `groupby` when I realized that `takewhile` didn't quite do the trick (or at least it would need to be iterated and would look really messy).

Comment: I also tried it with `takewhile`, but `groupby` is the elegant way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
def split_names(names):
    for s in names:
        last_names = []
        name_parts = s.split()
        while name_parts and name_parts[0].isupper():
            last_names.append(name_parts.pop(0))
        yield ' '.join(last_names), ' '.join(name_parts)


names = ["OBAMA Barack", "DEL MONTE Alfredo"]
for last_name, first_name in split_names(names):
    print last_name
    print first_name
    print
```

prints:

```
OBAMA
Barack

DEL MONTE
Alfredo
```

Comment: Might I suggest renaming `firstnames` -> `name_parts`, `lastnames` -> `last_names`; and you want to test the whole string for `.isupper()` since you want append to last-names only when the name is all in uppercase.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: `firstnames[0].isupper()` tests the whole word (the first in the list) for case and then pops it and appends it to `lastnames`. Renaming to `name_parts` and `last_names` makes sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mis-parsed that mentally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
import re

a = "DEL MONTE Alfredo"
first, last = re.match(r'([A-Z ]+)\s+(.+)', a).groups()
```

or loop thru a list of words and filter out all-uppercase ones:

```
first = ' '.join(w for w in a.split() if w.isupper())
last =  ' '.join(w for w in a.split() if not w.isupper())
```

In my personal opinion, "the most pythonic" === "the simplest".

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
(?![A-Z][a-z])([A-Z ]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

Comment: It would help to be explicit that this is a regex, and how you intend it to be used. I.e., show the actual framing code.